# Is there an overview of changes in UIKit throughout history?

Tags: ios

Does Apple (or someone else) publish a list of changes affecting UIKit throughout history where one could quickly see how things have evolved?

The closest I could find so far are Apple's [iOS release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14-release-notes#Overview). Was hoping there is something more concise and focused on UIKit.

Background: We have a new teammate who's been developing iOS apps from 2010 to 2014, and he'll be helping out with frontend work only. I'm trying to help him get up to speed with all things UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS release notes are the most concise way of gaining an overview of what has been changed in UIKit. The style of the release notes has changed since iOS 12. A full list of iOS release notes can be found in the [Documentation Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Release%20Notes). Spanning iOS 5 to iOS 11, see [Whats's New in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008246) page.